# Is there an equivalent of ApplicationController but for Active Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

I'm using `ActiveJob` in my Rails app and trying to add some generic functionality that should be shared by all of my jobs (exception handling to be exact).

An example is -

```
class MyAbstractJob < ActiveJob::Base
  rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
    # do exception handling stuff ...
  end
end

class FooJob < MyAbstractJob
  queue_as :my_queue

  def perform *args
    # do job stuff ...
  end      
end
```

This pattern is analogous to the use of `ApplicationController` for controllers, which inherits from `ActionController::Base` and provides somewhere to implement shared facilities available on a any controller subclass.

This actually seems to work for the most part except when I try to call `queue_as :my_queue` - in which case I end up seeing -

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'queue_as' for #<Class:0x007f088905c970>`

I don't see references in the Rails doc to this particular pattern. Does anyone know a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is weird, I think that your code is correct. I have tested your code as is, did not change anything, and don't see any problems:

```
FooJob.perform_later
# Performing FooJob from Inline(my_queue)
# Performed FooJob from Inline(my_queue) in 3.81ms
# Enqueued FooJob (Job ID: 6fd5ea5c-06bb-46d8-943c-8cc6f1e6ac33) to Inline(my_queue)
# => #<FooJob:0x0000000464de90 @arguments=[], @job_id="6fd5ea5c-06bb-46d8-943c-8cc6f1e6ac33", @queue_name="my_queue">
```

I have put both classes into the `app/jobs` directory.

The error you have shown in your question seems to be inheritance-related. Are you sure that your `FooJob` class really inherits from the `MyAbstractJob`? Perhaps you might also need to reload Rails just to be sure.

If your problem persists, please post real classes code, not simplified examples.

Comment: Thanks! It's true, it actually works fine. The bug was elsewhere.